# Как правильно аннотировать декоратор

Tags: python, типизация

Как правильно аннотировать декоратор функции?

```
def upper_case(func: t.Callable) -> t.Callable[..., str]:
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> str:
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Если используете Python 3.10, то через ParamSpec, в документации даже пример показан на декораторе: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec Если более старая версия, то примерно как у вас в вопросе.

Comment: В документации mypy тоже есть пример с декоратором https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet_py3.html#decorators

Comment: @andreymal, о, спасибо, буду использовать, не видел такого варианта. Вот тут более подробно расписано: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#declaring-decorators